# How to execute batch file via PHP?

Tags: php, batch-file, command-line, exec

I tried to execute the batch file using exec command in PHP.
I just used it like:

```
$filename = 'test.bat';
exec($filename);
```

But didn't get any output. I tried this function with another command, it works fine.
Your suggestions would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: you should probably set the path on the $filename. maybe it didn't find the path of the file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main issue was of `path` and `permission`. I have gotten my batch file to execute.

Here is my solution:

1. I run my batch file from the same folder the php file is in.

   `exec("mybatch.bat");`
2. I make sure that Apache Service has enough permission to run the batch file. Just to test i used an administrator account for Apache to log on with.

Comment: Correct solutions, Both Batch file and php files are in same folder

Answer (score 2):

On **Windows** server mind the quotes. This is what works for me:

```
system('cmd.exe /c C:\myfolder\_batches\run_this_batch.bat');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
system("cmd /c C:[path to file]");
```

As "RichieHindle" said in a similar topic.

or try

```
exec("cmd.exe /c test.bat") ?
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to execute a command and have all the data from the command passed directly back without any interference, use the passthru() function.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php

Answer (score 1):

What I did was the following:

1. created a PHP file that contained :

   ```
   $gotIt = array();
   $file = "getMyIP.bat";
   exec( $file, $gotIt );
   echo implode("<br>",$gotIt);
   ```
2. Created a batchfile in the same folder

   ```
   @ECHO off
   ipconfig
   ```
3. Ran it and waited for the firewall to jump all over the action.

I then got an output like :

```
Windows IP Configuration


PPP adapter 3 USB Modem:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix . :
IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : ***.***.202.81
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ***.***.202.81
```

only theres numbers where the ***'s are

Answer (score 0):

As it is explained in the [exec doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

```
echo exec($filename);
```

or

```
exec($filename, $output);
echo $output;
```