# How to run php script that executes the .bat file?

Tags: php, batch-file

I facing error while running the below php script. My php script having the little code for executing the .bat file which is located on my local server.

PHP file code : -

```
<?php
    system("cmd /c C:\Users\my_computer_name\Desktop\sample.bat");
?>
```

sample.bat file code : -

```
@echo off
title This is your first batch script!
echo Welcome to batch scripting!
start calc.exe
```

When i remove `start calc.exe` from .bat file code it works fine.

Thank you in Advance....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute batch file via PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088379/how-to-execute-batch-file-via-php)

Comment: Can you tell us what the problem is?

Comment: When i am trying to run the script the server is loading and not getting the response.

Comment: @CarlosAlexandre my question is totally different.

Comment: Once try with `exec` function in PHP. You can run commands using the `exec` function. `http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php`

Comment: @phpfresher I have already tried with exec but it is not working for my code.

Comment: You're starting a program inside a bat with an process started by PHP, I don't think you can do that, @HarshBarach

Comment: @CarlosAlexandre I think it is possible but i can not find the way to do so.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059588/how-can-i-start-a-windows-gui-program-using-php Try that

Comment: @CarlosAlexandre The thread suggested by you having the direct execution of the .exe file but in my case i want to run .exe file from .bat file by php script.

Comment: Exec your bat after that, your exe or check your permissions with the bat, possibly the windows don't allowing you doing that with the apache instance or some kind of stuff

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144925/discussion-between-harsh-barach-and-carlos-alexandre).